# Ruby, date converstion 2018 Mar 28 to 2018-03-28

Tags: ruby, date

I have a column in a table that list the date of creation of each row, the column show dates like `2018 Mar 28`, the date search picker dates are like `2018-03-28`

How to convert each of the above format to the other one :

```
2018 Mar 28 to 2018-03-28
```

AND

```
2018-03-28 to 2018 Mar 28
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back and forth:

```
▶ ["2018 Mar 28", "2018-03-28"].zip(["%F", "%Y %b %d"]).
▷   map { |date, format| Date.parse(date).strftime format }
#⇒ ["2018-03-28", "2018 Mar 28"]
```

All possible formatters for [`Date#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: is there any way to convert just "2018-03-28" to "2018 Mar 28" without the zip or array output ? thanks,

Comment: Obviously by picking the respective variant: `Date.parse("2018-03-28").strftime("%Y %b %d")`.

Comment: Thanks  mudasobwa, and thanks to all others, a small question plz, I have now an array of string dates ['2018-03-28',..] and two string dates from the date picker, how to find out if all the dates in the array are in the range ? thanks.

Comment: Please post this as another question, since the answer won’t fit a comment.

Comment: Smth like this would work: `range.select { |date| (date_picket_start..date_picker_end) === date }`.

Comment: I posted a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562038/ruby-how-to-find-all-elements-of-the-array-are-in-the-dates-ranges

Answer (score 0):

```
'2018 Mar 28'.to_date.to_s
```

or `Date.parse('2018 Mar 28').to_s` should just work in reverse you can do `Date.strptime('2018-03-28', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: There is no `String#to_date` method in ruby.

Comment: the first one Date.parse('2018 Mar 28').to_s worked, but other conversion did not Date.strptime('2018-03-28', '%Y-%m-%d') , I got the same string '2018-03-28'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate question but:

You can use `'2018-03-28'.strftime("%Y %b %d")`

See:
https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

and
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime