# ruby, how to find all elements of the array are in the dates ranges

Tags: ruby

I have an array of string dates ['2018-03-28',.... '2018-02-18'] and two string dates from the date picker '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-28', how to find out if all the dates in the array are in the range ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you are confident the dates will be in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, there is no need to parse or substitute anything. And you can use `#all?` to determine if the array dates are all between the date picker dates:

```
>> dates = ['2018-03-28', '2018-02-28', '2018-02-18']
>> lower_limit = '2018-01-01'
>> upper_limit = '2018-03-28'

>> dates.all? { |date| date.between?(lower_limit, upper_limit) }
#> true

>> upper_limit = '2018-03-01'
>> dates.all? { |date| date.between?(lower_limit, upper_limit) }
#> false
```

You might make a method like this one:

```
def all_dates_between?(dates, lower_limit, upper_limit)
  dates.all? { |date| date.between?(lower_limit, upper_limit) }
end

>> dates = ['2018-03-28', '2018-02-28', '2018-02-18']
>> lower_limit = '2018-01-01'
>> upper_limit = '2018-03-28'

>> all_dates_between?(dates, lower_limit, upper_limit)
#> true
```

If you are unsure about the format of your inputs, then use a parsing method as suggested by @SagarPandya.

Comment: undefined method `between?' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x00000000055d1c90> (NoMethodError)

Comment: sorry  moveson, it was my mistake, I cut and pasted your array name instead of mine, it's working now.

Comment: @Fatna, please remove your comments. I will do the same when you've seen this.

Answer (score 0):

Update just use select since this date format is sequential:

```
dates = ['2018-03-28','2017-01-01','2018-02-18']
dates.select{|d| d.between?('2018-01-01','2018-03-28')}
```

And if you want to just know if all the dates are in the range:

```
dates.all?{|d| d.between?('2018-01-01','2018-03-28')}
```

Updated answer, sorry I was being lazy.

Comment: why did you take off - from range dates ?

Comment: see updated answer, though looks like others already got this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

dates = ['2018-03-28', '2018-02-18']
range = Date.parse('2018-01-01')..Date.parse('2018-03-28')

dates.all? { |date| range.cover? Date.parse date }
 #=> true
```